# Multidimensional List of Points

Tags: c#, list

How do I create a multidimensional list of points? I googled a lot, but I didn't find a working solution.

For example:

```
List<Point> lines = new List<Point>(new Point[] {});

Point[] points = {new Point(0, 1), new Point(2, 3)};
lines.AddRange(points);

MessageBox.Show(lines[0][1].X.ToString());
```

What is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a `List<Point[]>`, not `List<Point>`

Comment: @haim770 Thank you.

Comment: @Reese If you have found an answer, either mark is green or put your own answer and mark that green.

Comment: @haim770 Thank you, this helped me a lot. But I have still a quick question: Is there any way to use more than one data type (point and integer) in the same list? I'm afraid, the answer is "no". :X

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional List C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184145/multidimensional-list-c-sharp)

Comment: Clearly defining 'multidimensional list of points' would be a good start. 'multi-' anything is a bit vague, no?

Answer (score 3):

See if this helps:

```
List<List<Point>> lines = new List<List<Point>>();

List<Point> points1 = new List<Point> { new Point(0, 1), new Point(2, 3) };
List<Point> points2 = new List<Point> { new Point(0, 1), new Point(2, 3) };
lines.Add(points1);
lines.Add(points2);

MessageBox.Show(lines[0][1].X.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(lines[1][1].X.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a multidimensional list of strings:

```
        List<List<string>> matrix = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> track = new List<string>();
        track.Add("2349");
        track.Add("Test 123");
        matrix.Add(track);

        MessageBox.Show(matrix[0][1]);
```

Or in your case:

```
        Point p1 = new Point(); // create new Point
        p1.x = 5;
        p1.y = 10;

        List<List<Point>> points = new List<List<Point>>(); // multidimensional list of poits 

        List<Point> point = new List<Point>();
        point.Add(p1); // add a point to a list of point

        points.Add(point); // add that list point to multidimensional list of points

        MessageBox.Show(points[0][0].x); // read index 0 "(list<point>)" take index 0 of that list "(Point object)" take the value x. "(p1.x)"
```